# how to assign dynamic folder path URL in Jenkinsfile

Tags: linux, jenkins

i want to go
home/username/dir1/dir2/myfile

but file have dynamic value of username in Jenkinsfile

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic" in this case? Where would the dynamic value for the username be coming from? From a file, from a build parameter, from an environment variable, from somewhere else? If you just want it to be based on whichever user is the current user, you can just use the `$HOME` environment variable, as in `"$HOME/dir1/dir2/myfile"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$HOME` environment variable:

```
cd "$HOME/dir1/dir2/myfile"
```

https://opensource.com/article/19/8/what-are-environment-variables

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

Comment: It would be safer to quote the `$HOME` variable to avoid word splitting and globing. A user technically could set their home folder to a path that contained spaces.